# DropDownList containing list of files in a directory on Edit and Create views in MVC4 web application

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I want to display drop down box containing list of files in a directory on Edit and Create views in MVC4 web application. I have used this in my edit section of the controller:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/DownloadFiles"));
var filesListing = directory.GetFiles().ToList<FileInfo>();
ViewBag.zipListing = filesListing;
```

and this in the edit view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DownloadName, new SelectList   (ViewBag.zipListing).AsEnumerable())
```

Which works fine, (*DownloadName* is the name of the table field), It updates the field and displays correct db table item on Edit page load. **However** If I try to use this in the Create view It errors out complaining about Null or cannot find reference.

I have a copy of the block:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/DownloadFiles"));
var filesListing = directory.GetFiles().ToList<FileInfo>();
ViewBag.zipListing = filesListing;
```

in the Create section of the controller with the var *filesListing* and ViewBag.*zipListing* renamed to avoid confusion (I guess I should put the dir reading to list stuff in a single place but one thing at a time maybe..)

Any ideas how to use this directory listing as a drop down in the Create view please?
I have tried many variations but nothing seems to work. Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Does your `Create` action method is getting hit when you navigate to Create page ?

Comment: If I take out the dropdown list from the create page everything else works

Comment: So, in your [HttpGet] of create page contain viewBag.zipListing as empty

Comment: Try debugging and check whether you have viewBag empty or not

Comment: Hmm. It is empty. But why when I add an @if (ViewBag.zipListing != null) { <h3>@ViewBag.zipListing</h3> } to the Edit view I get a "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.IO.FileInfo]" but with the create view nothing?? More confused than ever :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using ViewBag, have you thought of just adding a property to the model you are binding to the create view like so:

```
public List<FileInfo> FileList 
    {
        get
        {
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DownloadFiles"));
            return directory.GetFiles().ToList<FileInfo>();
        }
    }
```